# Item Id using webdav url using anguilla framework?

Tags: 2011, gui-extensions

Is there a way to get the ItemId using Anguilla like we get it using coreservice ?

Something like this

```
var item = $models.getItem('webdavURl');
```

Comment: I think because the context is the GUI then it assumes you always have the URI available when you start your action.  Unfortunately, the JS API is explicitly built to support the needs and screens of the Tridion GUI and within that context.

Comment: OK Thanks for the useful information :).

I am actually trying to disable a GUI button based on the other items property. Only relation i can make with the other item is using the name and forming the webdav url.